# Displaying Data and Images in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-lazyadapter

I'm Developing an Application. I'm displaying Thumbnail Image and Corresponding data with the image in ListView the data and images both are downloaded and parsed through XML parsing For Displaying images I used this tutorial

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)

But I'm not getting how to display the parsed data in ListView.

Thank you

Abhishek

Comment: post your `getView()` of Adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what u should do..

1. After parsing the data create objects for each row in listview(i.e,use a Custom Class)
2. Iterate through all the objects
3. Add to listView Adapter
4. Use listview.notifyDataChanged() function everytime.

This should do the trick..;)

Comment: Iterate through all the objects....is that mean the same as we have done with images...ok......Illl get back to u in some time

Answer (score 1):

By using the `BaseAdapter`, its possible.Inflate a layout that have `textview`and Image view in
Listview row.

Answer (score 0):

Please look in below link for the tutorial. i am sure you will get to resolve you problem on your own

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html